# Magento 1.9.3.4 : How to install sample data after magento setup?

Tags: magento1.9.3, sample-data

I want to install sample data after successful magento setup.

What will be the process of installing sample data after magento installation in magento 1.9.3.4.

Thanks

Comment: Check this : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/how-to-install-sample-data-for-magento/

Comment: @SHPatel thanks for your reply. Is there any way to install the sample data using CLI like this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240597/842746)?

Comment: It is way of Magento-2.

Answer (score 0):

Install sample data before installing Magento, I have waste lot of time in this. [Read](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html) official documentation to install sample data.

To import database via terminal use this command

```
mysql -u <db_user> -p <database> < sample.sql

mysql -u root -p  test < sample.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento1(or simply Magento) CE sample data must be installed before you install Magento CE. There is no way of installing it after Magento installation. Doing this after Magento installation would possibly overwrite a few tables which should be not. Please refer to https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ht_magento-ce-sample.data.html

Answer (score 0):

Sample data install after magento setup is easy, you have to copy folders of sample data and replace it with old folder of setup.